# How to download the content of an API

Tags: api, rest, download

I would like to download the content of an API because I have the requirement of my app to be used without internet.
Or if you have any idea to how to manage this without internet

Comment: It would help to know which API you're accessing. And by download, do you mean have it stored on your local env to recover the content?

Comment: What API you're trying to download the content from?

Comment: https://www.emploi-store-dev.fr/portail-developpeur-cms/home/catalogue-des-api/documentation-des-api/api/api-repertoire-operationnel-des.html

Comment: I would like to download in json to use it locally

Comment: Follow-up question: What language? All of them can do REST API GET calls.

Comment: If it's only to download I can use Node.js, but my project env is Vue